# object oriented nature of PHP

Tags: php, oop

How does loosely typed structure of PHP go with object oriented nature of PHP?

Also, is PHP a pure object oriented language?

Thanks in advance.

I meant to point out the loosely typed nature of PHP. I meant the variable declaration, to be precise. How does this drawback of PHP go with its object oriented nature. Does PHP5 have pure object oriented features?

Comment: What specifically are you referring to by that first question? With a sprinkle of orange they go together pretty well.

Comment: There is no problem with dynamic types and OO. Have a look at Python and JavaScript. So what is your question actually about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, PHP is not a OOP-only language. In fact, they implemented OOP later on.

The losely typed nature of PHP can be a bitc*, but at the same time it can be very handy. I don't really see a problem with that. If you want to use strict typing, you have to force it in your code. You can explicitely cast variables to a specific type:

`$integer = (int) $stringVariableWithIntegerValue;`

And you can force a check on type using the `===` operator. In my opinion PHP is not a complete OOP implementation, but it works pretty well since 5.x.

```
$integer = 1;
$string = "1";

if($integer === $string) { // Will be false
...

if($integer == $string) { // Will be true
...
```

Answer (score 2):

> I meant to point out the loosely typed nature of PHP. I meant the variable declaration, to be precise. How does this drawback of PHP go with its object oriented nature.

You somehow seem to be under the impression that dynamic typing is a "drawback". It's not, it's just different. It does have its pitfalls, but so does pretty much every type system.

A variable can be any type. It can be an object as well. You can explicitly (manually) type check when you need to. There's syntactic sugar for actual type hinting of objects for function parameters. You can duck type to take real advantage of dynamic typing and objects. Or you can use none of that. It works fine.

> Does PHP5 have pure object oriented features?

Define "pure". PHP has objects. PHP is *not* an object oriented language. And certainly not a "pure" one for that matter. PHP's OOP feels pretty bolted-on (which it is), but it gets the job done without killing kittens.

Comment: being loosely typed also means being unsafe

Comment: @ruki In regards to what? *Type safety* has nothing much to do with dynamic or strong typing. *Application safety* has even less to do with it, given a programmer who knows what he's doing. You seem to come from strong/statically typed languages and feel insecure working with a dynamic type system. That's just the way it is, it's *different*, that's all.

Comment: I'm sorry I dont completely agree with you. Forcing the programmers to be careful on types an be specifically correct avoids whole lot of bugs and errors. what more can one demand?

Comment: @ruki That goes both ways. Dynamic type systems are specifically useful in a web environment, where every IO is via strings for all data types. It lets you get away with writing less code, which is helpful when you're spending half your time refreshing your browser during development. That's an *advantage*. On the flip side of course, you actually have to *understand* all the automagic that's going on and know when and when not to type check. Writing good dynamically-typed code takes experience, just as for statically-typed code. That's a holy war as old as the programming profession though.

Comment: Well you have shown both the sides of the coin here. Lets atleast this holy war between us. Cheers! Best of luck